# How can I retrieve data from 'any' ajax request being completed using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

I need to check whether or not a user is logged in or not based on a session. I know there are other ways like setting setInterval, etc to get this data back, but what I'm wondering is there a way to see the data requested back from a ajax request on a global scale such as:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){ //show data });
```

I'm wondering this specifically because I have all my ajax calls on the front end being filtered through one method on the server side and in that method, I'm just returning a variable if the session is dead. I'd much rather be able to check that variable from one place rather than have to check it in every method before throwing a session error.

Is this possible or is there a way to retrieve the data through the global request?

Comment: check for `xhr.responseJSON` in `ajaxSuccess` ... will not be truthy if dataType is html, xml or text  **https://jsfiddle.net/1orxvwue/**. Or check response headers if that is how you identify login status

Comment: Or perhaps better ajaxComplete if you don't return 200 status

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you! xhr was undefined based on success but adding the ajaxComplete instead allowed my xhr response to come through clean. This is exactly what I was looking for!